# Discord.js send hyperlink on normal message just like in user message

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

as a user, you can send hyperlink message in discord using

```
[Text](http://example.com)
```

and it'll be embedded like this:

[image]

.

however, if I used a Bot to do it with discord.js, using the code:

```
await source.channel.send("[text](http://example.com)")
```

it won't embed:

[image]

is it possible to do this like the user or it's simply impossible for bots to do it?

Comment: Only bot users can send such links. Normal users can't.

Comment: @user15517071 it only works in embeds and interaction replies

Answer (score 4):

You need to format that message into hyper link.

```
const msg = Formatters.hyperlink("", "http://example.com", text);
await source.channel.send(msg);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Formatters?scrollTo=s-hyperlink

Comment: .hyperlink returns a string which like the above, it's still not embedded for some reason

Comment: @Aeiddius it only works in embeds and interaction replies

Comment: You no longer need to import Formatters, all the Formatter types are directly exportable from discord.js https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/formatters.html#basic-markdown